# Send offline Message Notification to HTTP URL from eJabberd

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I have requirement where I need to notify my own server whenever there is an offline message. Current solution require you to hardcode FCM tokes, Apple APN certificates et al inside. But my requirement is to just send user JID and may be number of offline messages (optional).

When ejabberd detects there is new offline message, I want it to call my own HTTP endpoint with the information (at least JID with offline message) instead of sending FCM/APN messages directly.

Where do I start? Is there any module or library that I can use as starting point.

I have zero Erlang knowledge and long ago I learned Elixir if that is relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do I start? Is there any module or library that I can use as starting point.

To start with, check https://github.com/raelmax/mod_http_offline/
and
https://github.com/izandromm/ejabberd_mod_offline_post

Those modules may be obsolete and not work correctly with recent ejabberd versions, but maybe you can find some forks that are updated.